# How to make c++filt to work for all C++ names?

Tags: c++, c++filt

When I try to demangle some names from standard C++ library like:

```
$ c++filt _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
std::ios_base::Init::~Init()
$ c++filt _ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E
std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))
```

then it works with many names. However there are some names which cannot be demangled like:

```
$ c++filt _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_trait
_ZSt4endlIcSt11char_trait
$ c++filt _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcE
_ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcE
```

c++filt doesn't seem to succeed on it. Why last two names are not demangled correctly and how to demangle them?

Comment: You probably should indicate your OS name and flavour, the version of the C++ compiler in use, and the version of c++filt.

Comment: I suspect the names where it doesn't work are actually illegal. E.g. the last identifier of the first one should have eleven characters, but only ten are there. Also `char_trait` sounds just as if the mangled name were cut in the middle. Maybe something in your processing pipeline strips down the names of long identifiers, which makes them illegal as far as name mangling is concerned.

Comment: my fault, it seems that readelf didn't print whole name of names which couldn't be demangled because these names are too long. nm helped in this case and printed whole names. topic to close.